# VBA Excel implement COUNTIF function

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to implement a "COUNTIF()" function in my vba excel application. I know how to do this programatically but I want specifically to implement this as a formula so that later changes in the sheet will hold. This is the problematic line:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 20).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R11C7:R12C7;"">0"")"
```

It results in the following error:

```
Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Comment: Is your computer's regional system setting for *List Separator* a semi-colon (less common) or a comma (predominant)?

Comment: In the sheet itself, a ; suffices. However, I tried to use a , in the formula and it worked.

Comment: VBA assumes US formatting unless otherwise specified (which you could do here using `FormulaR1C1Local`)

Comment: @Rory - that sounds like the *Answer* from here.

Answer (score 2):

VBA defaults to US formatting unless otherwise specified - which you could do here using `FormulaR1C1Local` - so you need to use a comma separator, not a semicolon.